# Make link active when page load

Tags: jquery

Okey i got these links and its working fine whit the add and remove class.
But how do i make one of the links active when im loading the page so you can se whits page you'r on ?

HTML:

```
<ul>

    <li class="red btn"><a href="#tildig">link</a></li>
    <li class="blue btn"><a href="#kontakt">link</a></li>  

</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.red.btn { float:left; margin: 0 0 0 5px ; width: 41%; height:30px; background-image:url(../image/rod_bnt.png);}

.red.btn.active { background-image:url(../image/rod_bnt_pil.png); height: 40px; }

.blue.btn {float:right; margin:0 5px 0 0; height:30px; width: 41%; background-image:url(../image/blaa_bnt.png); }
.blue.btn.active { background-image:url(../image/blaa_bnt_pil.png); height: 40px;}
```

Script:

```
<script type="application/x-javascript">
$(function() {
    $('li.btn').click(function(){
        // Add "active" to the clicked element and
        // get all siblings and remove "active" from them
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });

});
```

Comment: your code works fine, at least for hash links: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/QVFvK/1/

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$('li').each(function(){
    if(window.location.href.indexOf($(this).find('a:first').attr('href'))>-1)
    {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Here I loop over all `li`s and I assumed that the text the `a` tag is a part of the page url. of course you can modify your selector to get 'em

Comment: I am making a web app so i link to div's. so it look like this in the url bar:
www.domain.com/#sideone

And then the divs i my html look like this:
<!-- Start of page -->

<div data-role="page" id="index">
  <div data-role="header" data-nobackbtn="true"> </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <p>Loading ...</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer"> </div>
</div>

<!-- End of page -->

Comment: I edited my answer to use `attr('href')` of `a` tag to set the active link class , try it

Comment: Unfortunately it did not solve the problem. Could it have something to do with a:first link to a href and not to a div?

Comment: What I understand is you want to highlight the active `li` which contains link to target `div`, could you show us sample of your html containing the `ul` to give you the correct answer?

Comment: Found this on Google.  Wanted to thank you because it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

How about not doing it with JS at all? Add an ID to your body tag on each page, and you can do something like:

```
#body-red .btn.red { background-image:url(../image/rod_bnt_pil.png); height: 40px; }
#body-blue .btn.blue { background-image:url(../image/blaa_bnt_pil.png); height: 40px;}
```

Comment: That won't do it. Because im making a web app and when you slide the pages it disappears and show up again :)